# split string only by the first occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: julia

I would like to split a string by the first occurrence of `.`.

```
julia> a = "x1.y1.xyz22"
"x1.y1.xyz22"

julia> split(a,".")
3-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "x1"   
 "y1"   
 "xyz22"
```

How is it possible in Julia to split a string only once to get:
     "x1"
     "y1.xyz22" ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `limit` keyword.

For this kind of questions you can also efficiently use the inline documentation.. just type `?split` (or any other function or type) in the console to retrieve a nice explanation of the function, their arguments and often usage examples. In this case:

```
help?> split
search: split splitext splitdir splitpath splitdrive rsplit splice! displaysize @specialize @nospecialize

  split(str::AbstractString, dlm; limit::Integer=0, keepempty::Bool=true)
  split(str::AbstractString; limit::Integer=0, keepempty::Bool=false)

  Split str into an array of substrings on occurrences of the delimiter(s) dlm. dlm can be any of the formats allowed by findnext's first argument (i.e. as a string, regular expression or a function), or as a single character or collection of characters.

  If dlm is omitted, it defaults to isspace.

  The optional keyword arguments are:

    •    limit: the maximum size of the result. limit=0 implies no maximum (default)

    •    keepempty: whether empty fields should be kept in the result. Default is false without a dlm argument, true with a dlm argument.

  See also rsplit.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> a = "Ma.rch"
  "Ma.rch"

  julia> split(a,".")
  2-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
   "Ma"
   "rch"

  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  Splits an HyperRectangle into two along an axis at a given location.
```

Answer (score 8):

The [`limit`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.split) keyword argument will set the maximum number of chunks in the result:

```
julia> split("abc.de.fg.hij.k", "."; limit=2) # split at most once
2-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "abc"        
 "de.fg.hij.k"

julia> split("abc.de.fg.hij.k", "."; limit=3) # split at most twice
3-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "abc"     
 "de"      
 "fg.hij.k"
```